# How to recreate this Subquery to a View

Tags: view, subquery, mariadb

MariaDb does not support Subquerying, so i am trying to figure out the best method to take this query and turn it into a view. I am not 100% sure how to do this, as i know i need to create multiple views to do this, but i am uncertain on how to break this up.

I have been requested to create a view from this dataset and i was able to create this query with (subqueries), but now i need to turn it into a view, which i have hit a wall on, as i do not know where to start when trying to break this up into digestible pieces to create the multiple views to create the master view, which is this query.

```
SELECT
`TestDelete`.`CustomerInputName` AS `CustomerInputName`,
`TestDelete`.`customerInputCustid` AS `customerInputCustid`,
( CASE WHEN ( `TestDelete`.`YQ` = '2017Q1') and `TestDelete`.`customerInputCustid` in (select `portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP`.`customerInputCustid` from portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP)
THEN `TestDelete`.`Quarter` 
WHEN ( `TestDelete`.`YQ` = '2017Q1' and `TestDelete`.`customerInputCustid` not in (select `portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP`.`customerInputCustid` from portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP)) or 
( `TestDelete`.`YQ` = '2017Q2' and `TestDelete`.`customerInputCustid` not in (select `portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP`.`customerInputCustid` from portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP)) or 
( `TestDelete`.`YQ` = '2017Q3' and `TestDelete`.`customerInputCustid` not in (select `portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP`.`customerInputCustid` from portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP)) or 
( `TestDelete`.`YQ` = '2017Q4' and `TestDelete`.`customerInputCustid` not in (select `portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP`.`customerInputCustid` from portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP)) or 
( `TestDelete`.`YQ` = '2018Q1' and `TestDelete`.`customerInputCustid` not in (select `portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP`.`customerInputCustid` from portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP)) or 
( `TestDelete`.`YQ` = '2018Q2' and `TestDelete`.`customerInputCustid` not in (select `portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP`.`customerInputCustid` from portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP)) or 
( `TestDelete`.`YQ` = '2018Q3' and `TestDelete`.`customerInputCustid` not in (select `portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP`.`customerInputCustid` from portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP)) or 
( `TestDelete`.`YQ` = '2018Q4' and `TestDelete`.`customerInputCustid` not in (select `portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP`.`customerInputCustid` from portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP))
then 'First'
END ) AS `2017Q1`
```

Comment: `MariaDb does not support Subquerying` ... what? Not according to [their documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/subqueries/)

Comment: @PaulT. yes, views in MariaDB do not support subquerying, but you can subquery if you save as a query. What i did was created this query that i now need to turn into a view and was hoping to get some help on how i could best transform this query that has many subqueries into a view?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this would be equivalent, but faster:

```
`TestDelete`.`YQ` IN ('2017Q2', '2017Q3', ...)
     AND NOT EXISTS(
           SELECT 1 FROM portfolio_review_ACC1_2017Q1_REUP
               WHERE customerInputCustid = TestDelete.customerInputCustid
                   )
```

Meanwhile, your `SELECT` seems to be missing at least `FROM customerInputCustid` ??